# Does QLThumbnailImageCreate still support webarchive

Tags: quicklook, webarchive

In the past QLThumbnailImageCreate would return an NSImage from a url pointing to a webarchive.  It's not doing so now.  Is this a bug, or do I not understand something?

Comment: Please file a bug.

Comment: I tried to use Feedback Assistant to create a bug report.  It didn't reference Monterey 12.01.  I explored it a bit, but found Feedback Assistant instructions too obscure to waste my time on.